# MuleSoft Application Consumer of a Kerberos Secured API

Tags: rest, api, kerberos, mulesoft

I am currently developing a Mule 4 cloudhub interface that need to consume data coming from a Kerberos Secured API. I am having problems using the HTTP connector to use my keytab to authenticate

I can successfully issue a CURL command to the API but I can't

I have issued this from my machine with the provided keytab

curl -i -v -X  GET -H "Accept: application/json" --negotiate -u: http://hdp-master-db.test.edu.au:8080/test_rest/AU

Can you advise on how to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTTP Connector documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-request-ref) the HTTP Request supports these four authentication methods:

- Basic
- OAuth
- NT LAN Manager (NTLM)
- Digest

It seems that it doesn't support Kerberos.

Comment: does that mean its a custom development?

Comment: Yes. The HTTP Connector is open source so you could try to extend it: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-http-connector